# Flash as3 process XML Doctype Entities

Tags: xml, apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

i've got a XML similar to the following example:

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE descriptor-layout 
[
   <!ENTITY prefix "http://www.myurl.com" >
]>



<xml>
....
</xml>
```

the prefix Entity is used in several tags like this:

```
<child src="&prefix;/mypath/mydata.xml" />
```

So my question is, wether there is anyway to process the listed Entities automatically (like it's possible in PHP) or if the only way to replace the &prefix; tags in the document is to do this by hand?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that AS3 does not come with your requested functionality out of the box.  In fact, to even get at the DOCTYPE information, you may have to use the legacy class, [XMLDocument](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/xml/XMLDocument.html#docTypeDecl).

Comment: I've noticed that one too, but since it doesn't do the required replacements either i will have to do this by hand..

Thanks anyway! :)